# How to create git submodule from existing directory?

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules

I have a project with many sub-directory. All of them are independent from each other and I wanna to transform each directory to git's submodule. How could I do this without made conflict between submodule repos and main git repository of project?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you gone through one of the many Git submodule tutorials out there? http://blog.joncairns.com/2011/10/how-to-use-git-submodules/  or http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/git-submodules-workflows-tips/ or https://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/

Comment: Let's note that out of the three links given by @nwinkler, only the atlassian link will mention the interesting alternative of using git subtree instead of git submodule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git subtree split` to split up each subfolder into a new git tree.

Then use it to create a new git repository.

Refer to the man pages to figure out the usage of `git subtree`.